# microsoft sql server management studio express store db in memory?

Tags: sql, database, memory

I have a database intensive test I'm running that uses a small database ~100MB.

Is there a way to have microsoft sql server management studio express store the database in memory instead of hard drive?  Is there some option I can select for it to do this?

I'm also thinking about a ram drive, but if there is an option in mssmse I'd rather do that.

Comment: If there's enough memory available, the data will naturally get stored in memory-based caches as you use it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Management Studio has nothing to do with how the database is stored. The SQL database engine will, given sufficient memory, cache appropriately to speed up queries. You really shouldn't need to do anything special. You'll see that the initial query is a bit slower than the ones that run after the cache is populated, that's normal.

Don't mess with a RAM drive, you'll be taking memory away from SQL to do it and will probably end up less efficient. If you have a critical need for fast disk, you'll either need to look at a properly configured array or solid state drives.

There are ways to performance tune SQL to specific applications, but it's very involved and requires a deep knowledge of the specific SQL server product. You're better off looking at database design and query optimization first.

Realistically databases around 100MB are tiny and shouldn't require special handling if properly designed.

Comment: Actually I can see the sqlservr.exe process taking up 240MB of memory atm so I guess it has enough.